# some doubts about polyglossia

Tags: polyglossia

This is the mwe from which the error can be seen.
If `\begin{otherlanguage}{french}` and `\end{otherlanguage}`, I get `Extra }, or forgotten \endgroup error`.

With `\selectlanguage{french}` no error and it doesn't need the end command so in this case I don't know if in the right part of the chunk the Italian language has been selected.

With `\textfrench{......}` no error but I think this is not the right command  because of the manual: "the command becomes available for short insertions of text in that language".

Given that I have many hundreds of `reledmac` chunks and given that I have already set up all the left side part of the chunks with the couple "begin language", "end language", I would like to know if is my the fault or `polyglossia` fault.

```latex
\documentclass[a4paper,twoside,openright,10pt,final]{memoir}
\usepackage{polyglossia}
\usepackage[series={A,B},noledgroup,noend,noquotation,noeledsec]{reledmac}
\usepackage[]{reledpar}
\setgoalfraction{.95}
\linenumincrement*{1}
\firstlinenum*{0}
\setRlineflag{d}
\setlength{\Lcolwidth}{66mm} 
\setlength{\Rcolwidth}{66mm} 
\AtBeginPairs{\sloppy}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainlanguage{italian}
\setotherlanguage[automaticspacesaroundguillemets=false]{french}
\setotherlanguage{hebrew}
\setstocksize{303mm}{216mm}
\setpagecc{297mm}{210mm}{*}
\settypeblocksize{220mm}{136mm}{*}
\setlrmargins{35mm}{*}{1}
\setulmargins{30mm}{*}{1.4142}
\setheadfoot{10mm}{10mm}
\setmarginnotes{8mm}{25mm}{10pt}
\checkandfixthelayout

\begin{document}

    \begin{pairs}
        \begin{Leftside} 
            \beginnumbering
                \pstart
%\selectlanguage{french}
\begin{otherlanguage}{french}
%\textfrench{
Le français est une langue indo-européenne de la famille des langues romanes. Le français s'est formé en France (variété de la « langue d’oïl », qui est la langue de la partie septentrionale du pays). Le français est déclaré langue officielle en France en 1539.
%}
\end{otherlanguage}
                \pend
            \pausenumbering
        \end{Leftside}

        \begin{Rightside} 
            \beginnumbering
                \pstart
%\selectlanguage{italian}
Il francese è una lingua indo--europea appartenente alla famiglia delle lingue neo--latine. Il francese si è formato in Francia (varietà della lingua d'oil, che è la lingua della parte settentrionale del paese). Il francese è stato dichiarato lingua ufficiale in Francia nel 1539.
                \pend
            \pausenumbering
        \end{Rightside}
    \end{pairs}
\Columns

\end{document}
```

Comment: @egreg it doesn't work

Comment: I forgot to say that the problem is raised after last update of polyglossia

Answer (score 2):

With the most recent update to `polyglossia`, the `otherlanguage` environment has been slightly changed.

The `reledmac` package changes the same environment's definition in order to do other necessary things, but hasn't yet been updated to respect the change.

Solution: patch the version of `reledmac` to add the required code.

```latex
\documentclass[a4paper,twoside,openright,10pt,final]{memoir}
\usepackage{polyglossia}
\usepackage[series={A,B},noledgroup,noend,noquotation,noeledsec]{reledmac}
\usepackage[]{reledpar}
\usepackage{xpatch}

\setgoalfraction{.95}
\linenumincrement*{1}
\firstlinenum*{0}
\setRlineflag{d}
\setlength{\Lcolwidth}{66mm} 
\setlength{\Rcolwidth}{66mm} 
\AtBeginPairs{\sloppy}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainlanguage{italian}
\setotherlanguage[automaticspacesaroundguillemets=false]{french}
\setotherlanguage{hebrew}
\setstocksize{303mm}{216mm}
\setpagecc{297mm}{210mm}{*}
\settypeblocksize{220mm}{136mm}{*}
\setlrmargins{35mm}{*}{1}
\setulmargins{30mm}{*}{1.4142}
\setheadfoot{10mm}{10mm}
\setmarginnotes{8mm}{25mm}{10pt}
\checkandfixthelayout

\makeatletter
\AtBeginDocument{%
  \xpretocmd{\otherlanguage}{\xpg@set@group@aux}{}{}% \xpg@set@group@aux is missing in reledmac
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

    \begin{pairs}
        \begin{Leftside} 
            \beginnumbering
                \pstart
\begin{otherlanguage}{french}
Le français est une langue indo-européenne de la famille des langues romanes. 
Le français s'est formé en France (variété de la « langue d’oïl », qui est la 
langue de la partie septentrionale du pays). Le français est déclaré langue 
officielle en France en 1539.
\end{otherlanguage}
                \pend
            \pausenumbering
        \end{Leftside}

        \begin{Rightside} 
            \beginnumbering
                \pstart
Il francese è una lingua indo--europea appartenente alla famiglia delle lingue 
neo--latine. Il francese si è formato in Francia (varietà della lingua d'oil, 
che è la lingua della parte settentrionale del paese). Il francese è stato 
dichiarato lingua ufficiale in Francia nel 1539.
                \pend
            \pausenumbering
        \end{Rightside}
    \end{pairs}
\Columns

\end{document}
```

Comment: I filed a bug report: https://github.com/maieul/ledmac/issues/829

Comment: thanks, I would do a correction very soon.

Comment: thanks for your comment and your code. reledpar v2.24.4 fix this issue. It has been send on the ctan 10 min ago.